# Vim ctrlp only works with a git repo

Tags: vim, ctrlp

The vim plugin ctrl p only works for me into git repo.

Why does it need a .git file?

Be work i mean it is searching my entire machine when no .git file is found.

my settings

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
let g:ctrlp_match_window = 'top,order:ttb,min:1,max:30,results:30'
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = 'node_modules\|vendor/|DS_Store\|git'
set wildignore+=*/.git/*,*/.hg/*,*/.svn/*,*/.idea/*,*/.DS_Store,*/vendor
```

Also tried:

```
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'r'
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'c'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are after, it sounds like you want ctrlp to pick up all files system wide and not just the "project" root directory.

The `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode` flags you set would either tell ctrlp `c` - only show me files from current loaded buffers directory including subdirectories, or `r` the first `project` root directory as identified with some sort of hidden repository directory like `.git`. Neither of which suggests what I think you are asking for...

So I'll go out of a limb and suggest that you can probably update the global variable:

```
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlP /'
```

To look for all files, on a linux system. As detailed in the reader:

```
Run :CtrlP or :CtrlP [starting-directory] to invoke CtrlP in find file mode.
```

Or test the above with `CtrlP /` in command mode first.

Again, I've guessed what you wanted here...

Comment: You mean that ctrl p looks for the first hidden folder and searches from there. Okay, I get it now. I am new to vim and I didn't understand why ctrl p was searching everywhere on my machine.

Comment: No worries, glad it helped. Welcome to VIM, it's super fun!